# Update javascript variables after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I'm attempting to dynamically update a notice after the cart is updated via ajax. I can't seem to figure out how to re-update all variables so the calculation loop could run again. I tried wrapping the if statement into a function and calling that again inside of `updated_wc_div` but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
( function($) { 
  var membership_price = membership.price;
  //grab cart total from html
  var total = parseInt($('.order-total .woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace('$',''));
  compared_price = parseInt(membership_price) - total;

  //everything runs fine on load.

  if ( total < membership_price ) {
    message = 'For <strong>$'+ compared_price +'</strong> more, gain access to unlimited downloads. <a href="/series/unlimited-membership">Become a member!</a>';
    notice = '<div class="woocommerce-info">' + message + '</div>';
    $('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').html(notice);
  }
  //running this to know when ajax is called
  $(document.body).on('updated_wc_div',function( event ){
    $('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').empty();
    total = parseInt($('.order-total .woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace('$',''));
    //I believe problem is here, it doesn't update variable so it could loop again.
  });

} )(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you show a proper example of the problem you're facing? The code provided doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I added comments to maybe clarify. Right now, everything works on load, but when a user removes an item from cart, it is updated via ajax, which the code above doesn't update the notice.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I dynamically update an object after ajax call is being called:

```js
function getCart(user_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_total_cart.php",
    data: {
      'user_id': <?php echo $user_id; ?>
    },
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      var user = JSON.parse(response);
      var total_cart = parseInt(user.total_cart);
      $("#total_cart").html(total_cart);
    }
  });
}

function addCart(product_id, user_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_cart.php",
    data: {
      'product_id': product_id,
      'user_id': user_id
    },
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      getCart(user_id);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
  getCart(<?php echo $user_id; ?>);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="total_cart">Total Cart</div>

<input type="button" name="add_cart" id="add_cart" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addCart('<?php echo $product[id]; ?>', '<?php echo $user_id; ?>')" class="btn btn-info">
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to put your function inside the ajax function or make the ajax function "async:false"

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    async:false,   // <========   remove asynchronous property 
    data: {},
    success: function(result) {
    }
  });
  
  
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "", 
    data: {},
    success: function(result) {
    
    // Or put your function here
    }
  });
```